# How to stop Observable with interval

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

I am using angular.js. I have a service with observable and interval. I need other function in service or controller to stop this observable when action occur.

my service code:

```
'use strict';

import assert from 'assert';
import * as rx from 'rxjs';

export class RTDBService {

constructor($http, rtdbSettings) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$http = $http;
    this.rtdbSettings = rtdbSettings;
}

observable(asset, interval = 5000, tags) {
    assert(asset, 'Asset parameter not provided');

    const path = `${this.rtdbSettings.root}/${asset}`;

    return rx.Observable.interval(interval)
        .concatMap(() => this.$http.get(path))
        .map((res) => res);
  }
}
```

my component controller code:

```
'use strict';

import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
import dataViewTemplate from './data-view.component.html';

class DataViewController {
  constructor($scope, rtdb, $window) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$window = $window;
    this.rtdb = rtdb;

}

$onInit(){
    const interval = parseInt(this.interval);
    this.$scope.tags = (this.tags).split(',');
    this.$scope.data = this.rtdb.observable(this.asset, interval, this.$scope.tags).do(() => null, (err) => {
        this.$scope.dataStatus = this.getStatus(err.status);
    }).map(this.transformData.bind(this));
}


transformData(data) {
    // no important code
}

 getStatus(status)
 {
    // no important code
 }
}

export const DataViewComponent = {
  controller: DataViewController,
  template: dataViewTemplate,
  bindings: {
     asset: '<',
     interval: '<',
     tags: '<'
  }
};
```

Comment: What action do you want to stop the observable? It's not really clear what are you asking. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Seems like you could use `takeUntil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pace have mentioned in the comments: what you want is `takeUntil()`:

```
$onInit(){
    const interval = parseInt(this.interval);
    this.$scope.tags = (this.tags).split(',');
    this.$scope.data = this.rtdb.observable(this.asset, interval, this.$scope.tags).do(() => null, (err) => {
        this.$scope.dataStatus = this.getStatus(err.status);
    }).map(this.transformData.bind(this))
    .takeUntil(action$.take(1));
}
```

... where `action$` is an observable that corresponds to the action. The `take(1)` is to make sure the subscription ends after we've received the one action that will cancel the operation.